# How to empty the DataEventBuffer for Datalayer API?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to create an application to send and receive data to and from wear and handheld. I would like to empty the dataeventbuffer, I tried release, but that does no change. Any help will be great.

This is my code on the wear :

```
       accounts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Pressed","Now");
            PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/requestAccounts");
            int count=0;
            putDataMapReq.setUrgent();
           // PutDataRequest putDataReq;
            PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult;
           // putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt("key", count+1);
            putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putLong("time", new Date().getTime());
            PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();

            pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq);

        }
    });

  @Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.d("Inside","OndataChanged");

    Log.d("No: events",dataEventBuffer.getCount()+"");
    for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
            Log.d("URI",item.getUri().getPath());
            if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo("/sendAccountResponse") == 0) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
               // Log.d("Datamap",dataMap.toString());
                if(!dataMap.getString("accounts").equals("test")){
                    Log.d("accounts",dataMap.getString("accounts"));
                    //event.freeze();
                    dataEventBuffer.release();
                    Intent showAccounts=new Intent(this,AcoountActivity.class);
                    showAccounts.putExtra("accounts",dataMap.getString("accounts"));
                    startActivity(showAccounts);

                }
            }
        }
```

This is my code on handheld device:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.d("Inside","On datachanged");
    for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
            Log.d("Path",item.getUri().getPath());
            if (item.getUri().getPath().compareTo("/requestAccounts") == 0) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
               // if(dataMap.getInt("key")==1){
                    Log.d("Inside","if key==1");
                    dataEventBuffer.release();
                    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/sendAccountResponse");
                    int count=0;
                    putDataMapReq.setUrgent();
                    PutDataRequest putDataReq;
                    PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult;
                    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putString("accounts", getIntent().getStringExtra("accounts"));
                    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putLong("time", new Date().getTime());
                    putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
                    Log.d("Over","here");
                    pendingResult =
                            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq);
                    //event.freeze();


               // }
            }
```

Every time i close the app on the wear and start it again,and check the logs, the number of times it enters the for loop for "sendAccountResponse" keeps on increasing by 1. for eg if i start the app 5th time ,for the same session,and press the Accounts button, the flow will enter the ondatachanged for SendAccountResponse five times and so on. How do I empty the Dataeventbuffer?

Comment: What's your use case for this? Typically the API passes you a `DataEventBuffer` with changes coming from another node in the system; you process its contents, and then it's done. Why do you need to clear it?

Comment: I made some edit, can you look at it now and see if you can better understand my issue?

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. You don't need to "empty" the `DataEventBuffer`, it simply gets called (once) whenever a data item changes. I don't have time this morning to work through the rest of your code to figure out why the behavior you describe is happening - but hopefully, knowing that it's **not** the `DataEventBuffer`, you can track it down yourself.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is as follows. I hit the accounts button on the wear. i put data in datalayer in the path "requestresponse". the handheld's on ondatachanged has tracks the the given path and in its if condition puts some data for the key "accounts" and for path "sendresponse".the ondatachanged of the wear tracks for the path "sendresponse" and starts a new activity. I read a lot of articles and have been cracking my head to understand why the multiple activities are displayed everytime i close and reopen the app. i also tried the same with sendmessage, i encounter same issue.

Comment: You were right, it was not the dataEventbuffer, but the the ondatachanged was called multiple times, for a reason I dont understand.I resolved the issue by keeping the same code for onDatachanged , but instead of implementing a listener to an activity, I created two WearableListenerServices, one on handheld and one on wear. Thanks